# Issues while converting a <img> to <asp:Image> in ASPNET

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm converting a classic asp page with just the plain html 4.01 controls to asp.net 2.0 web

page. Although I'm able to replace most of the controls with the equivalent asp.net controls,

But i face issues with the styling of the controls. i.e The controls go out of

alignment even though they use the same styling information.

ex:

**Old Code**

```
<p class="menuitem" id="menu01">
<a target="" href="Category.aspx?ccat_id=152&amp;language=en-GB&amp;publication=3">
<img height="7" width="12" src="Webroot/visual/arrow-navi-right.gif" border="0" alt="">Item 1</a>
</p>
```

**New Replacement**

```
<p class="menuitem" id="menu01">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonManual" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Category.aspx?ccat_id=152&amp;language=en-GB&amp;publication=3">
  <asp:Image id="imgLinkManual" runat="server" Width="12" Height="7" ImageUrl="~/visual/arrow-navi-right.gif" ImageAlign="Left"/>
  <asp:Label ID="LblManual" runat="server" Text="Item 1"/>
</asp:LinkButton>
</p>
```

In this case, the Image and the Label ideally should have appeared something like

[image: Required]

But actually it is appearing as

[image: ISSUE]

Since there is no processing happening with the images (as they are just the icons) on the

server side. Should i restrict using the old way i.e using the old html controls.

Deeply appreciate for your time.

Comment: What's with the `ImageAlign="Left"`?

Comment: @Oded : If i dont use the ImageAlign="left", the text is rendered right ontop of the image obscuring the readability

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET Image renders as an HTML image, so you should check the source code of your ASP.NET Image, not your ASPX code. Then you will be able to compare the 2 pieces of code and see what the differences are.

However, looking at your code, I can see an `ImageAlign` attribute on your ASP.NET Image which you don't have on your raw HTML image.

Also in your raw HTML code, you simply have `Item 1`, whereas in your ASP.NET code you have an ASP.NET Label with `Item 1` text value. A `label` is rendered as a `span` tag. Instead you should use a `Literal` control as this doesn't render any HTML markup.

Try changing to:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonManual" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Category.aspx?ccat_id=152&amp;language=en-GB&amp;publication=3">
  <asp:Image id="imgLinkManual" runat="server" Width="12" Height="7" ImageUrl="~/visual/arrow-navi-right.gif" /><asp:Literal ID="LtlManual" runat="server" Text="Item 1" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Yes, i have purposely added the ImageAlign attr on the ASP.NET Control. If i dont do it, the asp:label is rendered on top of the image. :(

Comment: The problem still persists even after replacing the Label ctrl with Literal.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ImageAlign="Left"` in your ASP control, it's the same as using `align="left"` in a normal HTML `<img>` tag. The behavior of that tag can be found here:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_ALIGN.html

I think you are better off using the html `<img>` tag when you don't need server-side interaction, but you could also remove `ImageAlign="left"` and get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With this approach it works on Mozilla Firefox but not on Internet Explorer :( The controls are scattered across whole of the asp:LinkButton

Comment: I don't know what you have in your CSS, but try `display: inline-block;` on the `<img>` tag, and put a `<div>` around the label and use  `inline-block` on that too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this worked. Adding a style attribute of text align on the paragraph level.
**style="text-align:left"** inside the

block

```
<p class="menuitem" id="menu01" style="text-align:left">

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonManual" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Category.aspx?ccat_id=152&amp;language=en-GB&amp;publication=3">
<img Width="12" Height="7" alt="" src="visual/arrow-navi-right.gif.gif">
<asp:Label ID="LblManual" runat="server" Text="Item 1"/>
</asp:LinkButton>

</p>
```

So do you guys find any issues w.r.t to performance / style of coding if i follow this approach ?